# In Google Sheets, is it possible to resize a spreadsheet while retaining its proportions?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently the only way to resize a full spreadsheet in Google Sheets seems to be using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire sheet and then dragging from either the last column (for resizing all columns) or from the last row (for resizing all rows). Unfortunately, this method doesn't preserve the current proportions of columns or rows, resizing either all rows or all columns to the same size.

**Is there any way to increase the size of a spreadsheet proportionally in Google Sheets - so that a full resize will add a proportional amount of size to each column/row without forgetting their current sizes?**

Answer (score 1):

The way to resize proportionally the row height and columns width without forgetting the current sizes is by using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). Specifically use setColumnWidth and setRowHeight to set the new sizes and getColumnWidth and getRowHeigt to get the current sizes. The values could be stored using the Properties Service or an auxiliary sheet.